# Oracle - Group By Creating Duplicate Rows

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, alias

I have a query that looks like this:

```
select nvl(trim(a.code), 'Blanks') as Ward, count(b.apcasekey) as UNSP,     count(c.apcasekey) as GRAPH,
count(d.apcasekey) as "ANI/PIG", 
(count(b.apcasekey) +  count(c.apcasekey) + count(d.apcasekey)) as "TOTAL   ACTIVE", 
count(a.apcasekey) as "TOTAL OPEN" from (etc...)

group by a.code
order by Ward
```

The reason I have `nvl(trim(a.code), 'Blanks') as Ward` is that sometimes `a.code` is a blank string, sometimes it's a `null`.

The problem is that when I use the `Group By` statement, I can't use `Ward` or I get the error

> Ward: Invalid Identifier

I can only use `a.code` so I get 2 rows for `'Blanks'`, as per below

```
1   Blanks  7    0   0  7   7
2   Blanks  23   1   1  25  30
3   W01     75   4   0  79  91
4   W02     62   1   0  63  72
5   W03     140  2   0  142 162
6   W04     6    1   0  7   7
7   W05     46   0   1  47  48
8   W06     322  46  1  369 425
9   W07     91   0   1  92  108
10  W08     93   2   0  95  104
11  W09     28   1   0  29  30
12  W10     25   0   0  25  28
```

What I need, is for the row with `'Blanks'` to combined into 1 row. Little help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can not use the alias in the `GROUP BY`, but you can use the expression that builds the value:

```
GROUP BY nvl(trim(a.code), 'Blanks')
```

Comment: When an answer works for you, please accept it; I noticed you never accepted an answer to your questions. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you find something more on what to do when someone answers you.